# How do I access variable values from one view controller in another?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, scope

I have an integer variable (**time**) in one view controller whose value I need in another view controller. Here's the code:

**MediaMeterViewController**

```
// TRP - On Touch Down event, start the timer
-(IBAction) startTimer
{
    time = 0;
    // TRP - Start a timer
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [timer retain];     // TRP - Retain timer so it is not accidentally deallocated

}

// TRP - Method to update the timer display
-(void)updateTimer
{
    time++;
//  NSLog(@"Seconds: %i ", time); 
    if (NUM_SECONDS == time)
        [timer invalidate];
}

// TRP - On Touch Up Inside event, stop the timer, decide stress level, display results
-(IBAction) btn_MediaMeterResults
{
    [timer invalidate];
    NSLog(@"Seconds: %i ", time);
    ResultsViewController *resultsView = [[ResultsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:resultsView.view];
}
```

And in ResultsViewController, I want to process **time** based on its value

**ResultsViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    if(time < 3)
       {// Do something}

    else if ((time > 3) && (time < 6))
       {// Do something else}

//etc...

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I'm kind of unclear on when @property and @synthesize is necessary. Is that the case in this situation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare `time` as a property in `MediaMeterViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger time;
```

Whenever you need to access an instance variable in another object, you should have the instance variable declared as a property, and when you declare a property you must always use `@synthesize` (to synthesize the getter and setter for that property).

Also take note that when setting `time` in `MediaMeterViewController` you must always use `self.time` instead of `time`. For example, `time = 0;` should be `self.time = 0;`.

To access `time` from your `ResultsViewController`, you would do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (mmvc.time < 3)
    {
        // Do something
     }

    else if ((mmvc.time > 3) && (mmvc.time < 6))
    {
    // Do something else
    }

    // etc...    
}
```

Where `mmvc` is a reference to your `MediaMeterViewController` object. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! I had a few issues getting it to compile, but I didn't realize that in addition to

#import "MediaMeterViewController.h"

I had to also have 

@class MediaMeterViewController.

Comment: Hi, i have question related to that, if i have a NSString at the place of NSInteger(time), am i obliged to do @property (nonatomic,retain) NSInteger time; ? or without retain ?? thx