# Organization of source files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My application has two classes: `exampleAppDelegate` and `exampleController`.

I import `exampleController.h` into `exampleAppDelegate.m` and `exampleAppDelegate.h` into `exampleController.m`.

When I try to use outlet or action from `exampleController` class in `exampleAppDelegate` class, the compiler returns the following error:

> use undeclared identifier and action not found.

The same problem happens when I try to use the variable from `exampleAppDelegate` in `exampleController`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [solution 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228242/how-to-access-string-variable-in-one-view-controller-to-another-view-controller) [solution 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548910/how-do-i-access-variable-values-from-one-view-controller-in-another) [solution 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685964/how-to-pass-a-string-value-from-one-view-controller-to-another-view-controller) [solution 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166376/how-do-i-access-a-variable-in-one-view-controller-from-another-view-controller) [solution 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008967)

Comment: Class names should start w/capital letters, btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same methods/selectors for events (like UIControlEventTouchDown ...) across multiple files, try adding them using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method instead of doing through IBAction (interface builder).
Also , I dont think  your approach of importing delegate in controller is correct.

Comment: My question about cocoa, not cocoa touch.